# Kibana operation on result

Tags: json, kibana, kibana-5

I have Kibana 5.2.1 and I want to make a simple operation on result. I have tried JSON input: {"script":"_value*2"}  but it throws "null_pointer_exception". If I don't write anything in JSON input field, it  displays correct number. How can I make sum and multiply it by two? [kibana error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q9xS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a scripted field to do this -

**Management** > **Index Paterns** > (your index name) > **Scripted fields**

Then to create one

```
doc['attempt'].value * 2
```

And just use that as your value.

Comment: I know this but I want to use result because I need sum of values that I will get by aggregate. The multiplication was just simple example that I need to alter the result a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe Kibana 5.2.1 doesnt support groovy anymore. What I believe your problem was, that you were missing "inline", and because of that it searched for stored scripts, hence the null pointer error.

```
{"script": {
"lang": "painless",
"inline": "_value*2"
```

}
}

Comment: Elasticsearch 5.2.1. says "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [script.groovy.sandbox.enabled] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"

Comment: i think 5.2.1 doesnt support groovy anymore, have edited answer

Comment: Error again, it doesn't know "_value" so therefore nullpointer exception.
"script":"_value*2","lang":"painless"}}],"caused_by":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"runtime error","caused_by":{"type":"null_pointer_exception","reason":null},"script_stack":[],"script":"_value*2","lang":"painless"}},"status":500}